# python error - TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, string, user-interface, tkinter, int

I have been building a flashcard app and have run into a roadblock while trying to implement a radiobutton. The issue is when run the menu shows up and your able to access the lesson, but the radiobuttons do not appear. Whenever the code is run this error shows up **TypeError: string indices must be integers** attached to the radiobutton function`balancing_radio_butto1 = Radiobutton(balancing_frame, text = balancing[answer_list[0]], variable=balancing_radio, value = 1)` if someone could explain the why this error shows up as well as how to fix it it would be much appreciated. Below is my code that I have so far.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from random import branding
import random

root = Tk()
root.title('Chemistry Flashcards')
root.geometry("500x500")


def balancing():
balancing_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)



global show_balancing
show_balancing = Label(balancing_frame)
show_balancing.pack(pady=15)

global balancing
balancing = ['balanced1', 'balanced2', 'balanced3', 'balanced4', 'balanced5', 'unbalanced1', 'unbalanced2', 'unbalanced3', 'unbalanced4', 'unbalanced5']

global balancing_state
balancing_state = {
'balanced1':'balanced',
'balanced2':'balanced',
'balanced3':'balanced',
'balanced4':'balanced',
'balanced5':'balanced',
'unbalanced1':'unbalanced',
'unbalanced2':'unbalanced',
'unbalanced3':'unbalanced',
'unbalanced4':'unbalanced',
'unbalanced5':'unbalanced',

}

answer_list = []
count = 1


while count < 3:
    rando = randint(0, len(balancing_state)-1)
    if count == 1:
        answer = balancing[rando]

        global balancing_image
        balancing = "C:/Users/Kisitu/Desktop/project/balancing/" + balancing[rando] + ".png"
        balancing_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(balancing))
        show_balancing.config(image=balancing_image)

    answer_list.append(balancing[rando])

    '''random.shuffle(balancing)'''
    count += 1

    random.shuffle(answer_list)

global balancing_radio
balancing_radio = IntVar()

balancing_radio_butto1 = Radiobutton(balancing_frame, text = balancing[answer_list[0]], variable=balancing_radio, value = 1)
balancing_radio_butto1.pack(pady=10)
balancing_radio_butto2 =  Radiobutton(balancing_frame, text = balancing[answer_list[1]], variable=balancing_radio, value = 2).pack()




my_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=my_menu, bg='#B7F7BB')

lesson_menu = Menu(my_menu)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="Lesson", menu=lesson_menu)
lesson_menu.add_command(label="balancing", command=balancing)
lesson_menu.add_separator()
lesson_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)


balancing_frame = Frame(root, width=500, height=500, )



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

`... text = balancing[answer_list[0]] ...`

balancing is a list, you are trying to index a value from the list.
you are passing answer_list[0] as index. 
answer_list contains random strings from balancing.
you are trying to index a list with a string like in

`balancing["balanced2"]`

maybe you could use a dictionary?

Comment: thanks i've fixed the error it was a problem with my naming not the actual code itself